# Lombok And Java Static Constructor Object Creation

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

Official document says that I can create object by using following approach:

```
 @Data(staticConstructor = "of")
class Foo<T> {

    private T x;
}
```

you can create         new instances of Foo by writing: Foo.of(5); instead of having to write: new    Foo(5);

This is a sample method to learn lombok.

```
package com.lombok.first;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.val;
@Data public class DataAnnot {
          @Getter @Setter private String name;
          private final int salary;
          
          
          
          @ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
          @Data(staticConstructor="of")
          public static class inner<T>{
          private T tally;
         }
          
          
     public static void main(String agrs[]){
     DataAnnot d= new DataAnnot(8);
     
     System.out.println(d);
   }
}
```

but when I add the line

```
 val obj= inner.of("object"); 
 System.out.println(d);
```

Eclipse flags error.
What am I  missing here? Perhaps I need to refresh my generics concepts, but how can I create an object of "inner" class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use `val obj = DataAnnot.inner.of("object");`?

I cannot tell for sure since you didn't specify where you added the code snippet.